# Do opportunity attacks end the target's movement?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, movement, opportunity-attack

Reading over chapter 9 (Combat) of the PHB, I stumbled across the following text, under the **Opportunity attacks** entry :

> The attack **interrupts the provoking creature's movement**, occuring right before the creature leaves your reach. (PHB, p. 195, emphasis mine)

While it seems obvious to me that the creature is allowed to resume it's movement afterwards, the text doesn't state so.

Am I assuming wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**You are correct; movement may be resumed after an Attack of Opportunity.**

Movement is "spent" by the foot; as in, if a creature has a movement speed of "30ft", then they can spend that much speed during a move action.  If they are interrupted by an opportunity attack after 10ft, then they still have 20ft left to spend.

To further support this, look at the following line from the "Sentinel" feat in the PHB:

> When you hit a creature with an opportunity attack, the creature’s speed becomes 0 for the rest of the turn.

"...speed becomes 0 for the rest of the turn." is the wording which denotes that the movement is interrupted and cannot be resumed.

Comment: From the point of view of an AoO attacker *trying* to stop someone: As well as the Sentinel feat, any attack which knocks the opponent prone helps. Although not as good as halting the opponent, they still have to spend movement to get up, and may not have enough to do what they were originally intending to do (or in some cases not enough to even get back up again).

Comment: Movement is not _resumed_, it is not stopped in the first place. It matters for a few cases.